# Get customer details using custom attribute

Tags: magento2

We are using a custom attribute on customer that references an ID on an external system. We want to get customer's details on a custom page by loading the customer by this custom attribute.

I tried using simple code as below

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create();
$customer = $om->loadByAttribute('ext_id','1234');
```

But this doesnt seem to work. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Collection to fetch the required objects:

```
protected function getCustomerCollection($ext_id) {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection');
     /** Applying Filters */
    $customerCollection
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('id','firstname', 'ext_id',  'email'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('ext_id', array('eq' => $ext_id));
    return $customerCollection->load();
}

$customerCollection = $this->getCustomerCollection($ext_id);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject $item */
foreach ($customerCollection as $item) {
    // do something with the item
    var_dump($item->getData('firstname'));
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Code-only answers aren't usually good on Magento.SE because we want to encourage other users to learn _how_ to solve their problems, and _why_ the solutions we provide are helpful. Could you update your answer to explain why it solves the OP's problem?